# Why it is returning same number of time value as its recursion fuction called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, python-itertools

In this program I create the subset of all possible set and after that I did the bitwise operation('OR','|') on every set and after that I add them and take the mod and print the answer.

For example :

```
n=3(Size of array or list)
b= 2 5 5
```

all possible sets :

```
[[2,5],[2,5],[5,5],[2,5,5]]
[2,5]=7, [2,5]=7, [5,5]=5, [2,5,5]=7
```

Add all of these: `7+7+5+7=26`

```
import itertools

def subs(l):
    res=[]
    for i in range(2,len(l)+1):
        for combo in itertools.combinations(l,i):
            res.append(list(combo))
    return res

def bitwise_operation(c):
#print("List of c : ",c)
if(len(c)>1):
        bitwise=c[0]|c[1]
        #print("Before del C : ",c)
        del c[0:2]
        #print("After  del C : ",c)
        c.append(bitwise)
        #print("After append C : ",c)
        if(len(c)>1):
            bitwise_operation(c)
print(c[0])
return c[0]

n=int(input())
bit=[]
a=list(map(int,input().split()))
b=[]
if len(a)!=n:
    exit()
else:
b=subs(a)
#print(b)
for j in range(len(b)):
    for k in range(len(b[j])-1):
        if len(b[j])>1:
            bitwise=bitwise_operation(b[j])
        #print(bitwise)
        bit.append(bitwise)
prev_ans=sum(bit)
ans=prev_ans%1000000007
print(ans)
```

The problem is that when I make the bitwise operation using the recursive `function(bitwise_operation) [2,5,5]=[2,5]->7,[7,5]->7..........` the return value for this is `[2,5,5]=7`

It returns `7, 7` twice in the same set.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the indentation for `bitwise_operation` correct?

Comment: `c.append(bitwise)` - is your intent to add the bitwise result to the end?

Comment: Is `7 7 5 7` the `bitwise_operation`'s expected output for `[[2,5],[2,5],[5,5],[2,5,5]]`??

Comment: It's not clear what you problem is or what your expected result is - when I execute `bitwise_operation([2,5,5])` it return `7` **only**.

Comment: Finally, your recursive function could be replaced with `functools.reduce(operator.or_, c)`

Comment: @wwii thank you kindly please tell me how this `functools.reduce(operator.or_,c )` will **work**.

Comment: @wwii  yes, you are right but when I execute `bitwise_operation(b[j])` it will return `7 7` *twice*.

Please execute this program when you got time :) .

Comment: Does `bitwise_operation` do what it is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here. You are appending the result for `b[3]` (the element `[2, 5, 5]`) twice.

```
for j in range(len(b)):
    for k in range(len(b[j])-1):  
        if len(b[j])>1:
            bitwise=bitwise_operation(b[j])
        #print(bitwise)
        bit.append(bitwise)
```

This is a very complicated way to do a simple thing. I'll re-label to clear up what you are doing.

```
for index in range(len(b)):
    element = b[index]
    for times in range(len(element)-1):  # do this one time for element of len(2) and two times for an element of len(3) 
        if len(element)>1:
            bitwise=bitwise_operation(element)  # change the value of bitwise and mutate the element
        #print(bitwise)
        bit.append(bitwise)  # append that value whether it changed or not.
```

So, when you run your outer loop, it appends the value for [2, 5, 5] twice, giving you the extra 7.

You can get the correct result by directly iterating over `b`.

```
for element in b:
    bit.append(bitwise_operation(element))
```

This should give you the correct answer.

On a side note, `bitwise_operation` can be greatly simplified by iterating directly over the list.

```
def new_bitwise_operation(lst):
    answer = 0
    for element in lst:
        answer = answer | element
    return answer
```